# Coinotron wont show updates from cgminer

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, cgminer

I type this into command on windows

```
C:\Users\developer\Desktop\cgminer-3.7.0-windows\cgminer.exe --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://coinotron.com:3334 -u exploithb.1 -p x
```

and it looks like its working, Im getting 1.4 MH/s for lite coin. But when i log into coinotron i don't see my workers Speed value and It stays at 0.0 KH/s. Could it be that I'm doing something wrong? I let it sit for a half hour to see if i see any updates and nothing ever shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it didn't show. These mining pools out there just like coinotron arent running super servers and there are multiple people connected and it cant always pull that kind of strain on the server to request up to date/time of your local hash speed, so it displays what it can for everyone. Also After initialy starting your miner you have to wait atleast 5-10 minutes depending on your bandwidth for cgminer to officially connect and for your worker to show some kind of data. In cgminer look for where it shows A:# and HW:#  if these values are 0 then the connection hasnt been made yet. Just wait for 5-10 minutes and its value should keep going up. Once you see its values going up look to the right there should be something that says shares accepted , its value should be going up in time as well. If A:# or HW:# has not changed and stays and 0 then something is wrong ,you need to reconfigure your commands that you typed for it.

If you find this helpful upvote :p